# How does the equation make sense in case of a Poisson process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

> $$P(N_1=2, N_4=6)  = P(N_1=2, N_4-N_1=4) = P(N_1=2) \cdot P(N_3=4)$$

How does the above equation make sense in case of a Poisson process?

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Why is $P(N_3=4)=P(N_4-N_1=4)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully the first equality is clear to you:
$$ N_1 = 2 \text{ and } N_4 = 6
\implies
N_1 = 2 \text{ and } N_4 - N_1 = 4.$$
Now, a Poisson process (by definition) has independent increments. This means, in particular, that the difference $N_4 - N_1$ is independent of $N_1$. Hence
$$ \Pr(N_1 = 2, N_4 - N_1 = 4) = \Pr(N_1 = 2) \Pr(N_4 - N_1 = 4).$$
Furthermore, it has what are called "stationary increments". That means that the distribution of $N_{n+m} - N_n$ depends only on $m$. Hence $N_4 - N_1 \sim N_3 - N_0$, and $N_0 := 0$. Hence $\Pr(N_4 - N_1 = 4) = \Pr(N_3 = 4)$.

Combining these results gives the answer! :)

---

You can read up on Poisson processes in Section 1.4 of [Perla Sousi](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~ps422/)'s lecture notes on "Applied Probability", available on her [website](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~ps422/); they're written jointly with Nathanael Berestycki. I highly recommend doing so; they're good notes!

Comment: *Hopefully the first equality is clear to you:* --- no. its not.

Comment: It's the statement "if $x = 2$ and $y = 6$, then $y - x = 4$" -- take $x = N_1$ and $y = N_4$ :)

Comment: Why is $P(N_3=4)=P(N_4-N_1=4)$?

Comment: That corresponds to the "stationary increments" part of my answer. In essence, Poisson processes correspond to arrivals, say of customers to a shop, and so "the number of arrivals between 1pm and 4pm is the same as between 12pm and 3pm". The linked lecture notes go into detail

Answer (score 1):

You don't define your notation, but I assume that the carrier space is divided into bins of equal width, the $N_i$ are the numbers of events in the first $i$ bins, and you have a Poisson point process that produces points in that carrier space.  Breaking down your equations:

- $P(N_1 = 2, N_4 = 6)$: We want to study the probability that $2$ events land in bin 1 and $6$ events land in the first $4$ bins.
- ${} = P(N_1 = 2, N_4 - N_1 = 4$:  If two events land in the first bin, then $6 - 2 = 4$ events land in the second, third, and fourth bins.  We have also made the two conditions independent, so ${} = P(N_1 = 2) \cdot P(N_4 - N_1 = 4)$.
- ${} = P(N_1 = 2) P(N_3 = 4)$: The Poisson process is memoryless.  The number of events landing in an interval only depends on the width of the interval.  The interval represented by $N_4 - N_1$ is three bins wide, so we can replace that with the probability of getting $4$ events in $3$ bins.

Comment: Why is $P(N_3=4)=P(N_4-N_1=4)$?

Comment: @user366312 : "the $N_i$ are the numbers of events in the first $i$ bins".  Since "the Poisson process is memoryless", the distribution of points landing in the first three bins is equal to the distribution of "events [that] land in the second, third, and fourth bins" taken together.  In fact, its the same distribution as the number of events landing in any three bins, including the first three bins.  Equal *distributions*.  We are not claiming that this use of $N_3$ is dependent on the number of events in bin one.